# Angular-cache $.getScript JS code

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, caching, angular-cache

I am using `$.getScript` to load some of my program code. My code looks something like this:

```
var mainJs = "/main.js";
$.getScript( mainJs )
    .then(function () {
        console.log("main.js loaded");
    });
```

The code works fine. However, I am thinking to use Angular-cache to do caching control on it. Is it possible to be done?

Comment: Are you trying to prevent it being loaded again or trying to save another trip to server?

Comment: @charlietfl I want to prevent it from loading again, even by next time user is visiting. It only try to get from server again when the cache is expired by angular-cache.

Comment: angular cache doesn't store anything for next visit either. i think you have your concepts of caching mixed up a bit. Caching this won;t prevent the script from running again within the same app session....is that your goal? If so you will need some service to keep track if it has been run or not

Comment: @charlietfl Isn't that angular cache can store as localStorage? Correct me if I am wrong..

Comment: no ... that is a different concept entirely. angular `$http` cache stores actual responses in javascript objects. Those are not maintained between page loads

Comment: Local storage is a concept of HTML, not angular itself. You need to specify what you want exactly.

Comment: Is this just data variables in that script? Or is it executable functions?

Comment: @charlietfl It's executable functions. I guess my question should be "how to run angular-cache cached executable scripts?"

Comment: That doesn't make a lot of sense either. If browser is set to cache it will...if not it will pull from server. There is no benefit in trying to cache this yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether angular is able to interfere the caching of jQuery. But by default `$.getScript` doesn't cache.

`$.getScript` is a shortcut of:

```
$.ajax({ 
    url: '',
    dataType: "script",
    cache: false
});
```

Reference: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/

> By default, $.getScript() sets the cache setting to false.

You need to use:

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    cache: true,
    dataType: 'script',
    ...
});
```

Comment: This doesn't prevent another request to server. It really has no impact at all. The `cache` of `$.ajax` is not the same concept as angular cache where data is literally stored in a datastore within page

Comment: @charlietfl It does make change. Please check http://jsfiddle.net/Lttg8ava/. Using `cache:false` makes the response code 200 every time. However, using `cache:true` makes subsequent response code 304, which means no more new content from server.

Comment: OK but concept is still different than angular cache. I really think OP wants to prevent this code running again. I get 200 with cache true also ...opps probably because I have cache disabled

Comment: from docs: `Note: Setting cache to false will only work correctly with HEAD and GET requests.`. The `cache` ajax does is just add a timestamp in url. So it doesn't even add it for script requests

Comment: script requests are `GET` requests. `cache` option applies to `getScript`.